# SQL UPDATE to INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE reservations SET name = :name, start = :start, end = :end, room_id = :room, status = :status, paid = :paid, customer = :customer, name_ship = :name_ship, equipment = :equipment, port = :port, ETA = :ETA, ETD = :ETD, service_id = :service_id, service_classification = :service_classification, job = :job WHERE id = :id");
```

Hi! 
I have this query and I would like to transfer it into INSERT format.
When I made it like this, nothing happens. Thank you for your advice

```
"INSERT INTO reservations (name, start,...) VALUES (:name, :start,...) WHERE id = :id";
```

Comment: Why do you have `where` criteria in your `insert` statement?  What datatype is `id`?  If it's auto increment, just remove the `where` criteria.  If not, you'll have to include that in your list of columns and values...

Comment: What do you mean "INSERT format"?  `INSERT` and `UPDATE` do two very different things:  you use the one that is the operation you want to accomplish.

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... WHERE` makes no sense, you can't do a conditional insert, but you can *conditionally* call your insert. Are you thinking of the [`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) feature?

Comment: Thank you. The deal is I have edit form and I woul like to put next to edit button copy button which is going to copy form (only room_id and is going to be changed if copy is selected, and ID of course). And even when I delete WHERE  criteria nothing changed.

Comment: I already figured it out. I used INSERT INTO reservations (name, start, ..) SELECT :name, :start, ... FROM reservations WHERE id = :id");

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing an `INSERT` you should drop the `WHERE` clause.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO reservations (name, start,...) VALUES (:name, :start,...)
```